# Android Library integration to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, billing

Alright, this is probably a pretty dumb question but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

I am trying to integrate the Android Billing Library from Github https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary

The only instructions in the readme are: Add this library to your project.

I have only ever integrated .jar files.  This comes as a zip and when unzipped has a bunch of folders and classes located inside it.

How do I "Add this library" to my project?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like download package available from your GitHub link contains the source code of several projects from Eclipse/ADT workspace. So, you can unzip the package and then just import those projects into your Eclipse workspace. After that you can add AndroidBillingLibrary project as dependency from your project properties / Java Build Path configuration panel.

Comment: Roger, thats what I ended up doing, forgot to update my question, thanks!